# Install Roblox on private server

Tags: server, local, roblox

I have written a simple game using Roblox Studio that is maths-based and is intended to help students in the school where I work improve their skills. I have had it green lighted by the head of the maths department.

The issue I have is we want children to be able to access this educational game only. Also, we don't want children to use their own accounts to sign in to Roblox for GDPR reasons. In short, we would like to install Roblox in the school server so that only the games that we choose are available.

Does anyone here know the procedure to install Roblox in a local server?

Any help appreciated.

Paul.

Comment: You may need to contact Roblox to see if something such as this is possible. Roblox Studio isn't usable without an account, however one owned by the school could be put onto each installation. There are versions of Roblox that work offline or on self hosted servers, however they are reverse engineered and sometimes outdated / insecure, nor are they officially or legally supported by Roblox.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this possible in my school we don't use Roblox but device connected to the school servers you should be able to blacklist roblox.com sites but white list the specific game.

In terms of the accounts Roblox requires an account to play and using guests is no longer possible. For example in my school when using Office we log in using our school accounts and not our personal Microsoft accounts. If you have the rest of Roblox blacklisted other than your maths game then if your students use there own account they wont be allowed play anything other than the maths game.

I know its and janky way of doing this and far from perfect but it's all that I can think of. Other than that you could of course do what pyknight202 said and just contact Roblox support.

Hope I could help in some way.
Crann

Answer (score 0):

Creating roblox accounts is really easy, and one single email can support up to 20 different accounts if not more.
The only solution I see is creating one per machine, also Crann's solution is strong as only whitelisting educational purpose games, blocking the rest.

If u want to prevent external people from enter the game u can create a group with all the machine accounts, and make a script to detect if the user is in the group, and if not u can kick the player specifying the reason or directly dont let him do anything. (I think u can also make the game only playable to people in a group, -I think-)

It is also possible to set max players to 1 if the game don't have multiplayer features. So it can be opened to everyone who wants to in solo mode.